# Why does making a new instance of a Javascript class overwrite an old instance?

Tags: javascript, class

Why does the last line in the following code output `there`? It appears that creating a new instance of the same class overwrites the old instance. Is there a way to prevent this behavior so the last line outputs `here` instead?

```
var one = function(params) {
    _params = params;

    var two = {
        load: function(params) {
            _params = params;

            return this;
        },

        getHere: function() {
            return _params.here;
        }
    };

    return two.load(params);
};

oldOne = new one({ here: 'here' });

console.log(oldOne.getHere());

newOne = new one({ here: 'there' });

console.log(newOne.getHere());

console.log(oldOne.getHere());
```

Comment: `_params` is declared as global and as such, shared by all instances

Answer (score 3):

That's not what's happening. The problem is you're not *declaring* your variables, so JavaScript decides to make global variables for you. Then, the global `_params` value is getting overwritten each time you call `one`.

Here's how to fix your code so it'll behave as expected:

```
const one = function(params) {
    let _params = params;

    var two = {
        load: function(params) {
            _params = params;

            return this;
        },

        getHere: function() {
            return _params.here;
        }
    };

    return two.load(params);
};

const oldOne = new one({ here: 'here' });

console.log(oldOne.getHere());

const newOne = new one({ here: 'there' });

console.log(newOne.getHere());

console.log(oldOne.getHere());
```

Now each invocation of `one` will declare distinct instances of `_params`.

Answer (score -1):

Your _param is global variable, to make it class scope you can use this keyword as

```js
var one = function(params) {
    this._params = params;

    var two = {
        load: function(params) {
            this._params = params;

            return this;
        },

        getHere: function() {
            return this._params.here;
        }
    };

    return two.load(params);
};

oldOne = new one({ here: 'here' });

console.log(oldOne.getHere());

newOne = new one({ here: 'there' });

console.log(newOne.getHere());

console.log(oldOne.getHere());
```

Comment: The `this._params` in the `one` prototype is never used